# android dynamically created spinner not scrolling

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have created a layout dynamically and added spinner and swipe layout to it via code in a fragment instead of xml files.

Everything works fine except that the spinner does not scroll.

The spinner's onItemSelected methods works fine though.

Here is the code inside onCreate method of the Fragment.

The canScrollVertically(-1) and canScrollVertically(1) methods for spinner return false. There is a main relative layout which contains two items. A spinner and then a swipe layout that is positioned below it. Swipe layout contains gridview.

```
parentLayout=new RelativeLayout(getContext());
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            parentLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

swipeView = new SwipeRefreshLayout(getContext());
            swipeView.setRefreshing(true);

swipeView.addView(gallery);

            mediaFolderSpinner = new Spinner(getContext());
            mediaFolderSpinner.setId(MEDIA_FOLDER_SPINNER_ID);

            spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            spinnerArray.add("All media");
            selectedFolder = spinnerArray.get(0);
            populateMediaFolders();
            spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray)
            {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                    /*return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);*/
                    TextView lbl = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    lbl.setText(getItem(position));
                    lbl.setWidth(500);
                    lbl.setHeight(75);
                    lbl.setGravity(Gravity.START);
                    int paddingSidePixels = FileUtil.getPixelsFromDp(5);
                    lbl.setPadding(paddingSidePixels, lbl.getPaddingTop(), lbl.getPaddingRight(), lbl.getPaddingBottom());
                    lbl.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black));
                    lbl.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white));
                    return lbl;
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                    /*return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);*/
                    TextView lbl = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    lbl.setText(getItem(position));
                    lbl.setWidth(500);
                    lbl.setHeight(75);
                    lbl.setGravity(Gravity.START);
                    int paddingSidePixels = FileUtil.getPixelsFromDp(5);
                    lbl.setPadding(paddingSidePixels, lbl.getPaddingTop(), lbl.getPaddingRight(), lbl.getPaddingBottom());
                    lbl.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black));
                    lbl.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white));
                    return lbl;
                }
            };
            mediaFolderSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            mediaFolderSpinner.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black));



            mediaFolderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectedFolder = spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
                    galleryAdaptor.createGrid();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });



            parentLayout.addView(mediaFolderSpinner);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mediaFolderSpinner.getLayoutParams();
            int marginPixels = FileUtil.getPixelsFromDp(5);
            rlp.setMargins(rlp.leftMargin, marginPixels, rlp.rightMargin, marginPixels);
            mediaFolderSpinner.setLayoutParams(rlp);



            parentLayout.addView(swipeView);

            if(TYPE == TYPE_IMAGE_VIDEO_MAIN) {
                mediaFolderSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams swipeLp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) swipeView.getLayoutParams();
                swipeLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, MEDIA_FOLDER_SPINNER_ID);
                swipeView.setLayoutParams(swipeLp);
            }
            else{
                mediaFolderSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this ? I have the same problem.

Comment: @That_some_guy I have posted answer. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try {
            Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            popup.setAccessible(true);

            // Get private mPopup member variable and try cast to ListPopupWindow
            android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(mediaFolderSpinner);

            //int height = 500;   //Default 500px
            int height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            if(CreatorActivity.creator.getmActivity().isPortrait()) {
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                /*if (Const.NAVBAR_HEIGHT > 0) {
                    height = height - Const.NAVBAR_HEIGHT;
                }*/
            }

            popupWindow.setHeight(height);
            /*popupWindow.setHeight(500);*/
        }
        catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // silently fail...
        }
```